# Communication between background.js and popup.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm trying to build a chrome extension which stores links that I press while holding down `shift` and `alt`. This is my first chrome extension, and if I'm not mistaken, the way I'm supposed to do this is have a `background.js` which does the event handling for when I click on a link. Then, when I click on the link, I want `popup.js` to access that link somehow and display it on the page for later use. What would be the best avenue for this? Should I use localstorage, store the link in there, then when I open up `popup.html` have `popup.js` access it through localstorage and grab it to display it? Is there any way to have them directly communicate with each other?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly access any methods/objects declared at background.js using `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage`.
Check http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getBackgroundPage for additional information.